# How to assign a value of 10^100 to an integer variable in C?

Tags: c

I was working on a problem to count number of digits in a number but according to the constraints the number should be of the range 10^100(10 to the power 100). I have tried it using limits.h but it did not work. Could anyone suggest a way to do that?

```
int main(){  

    int n=LONG_MAX;
    int count;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n!=0)
    {
        n=n/10;
        count++;
    }
    printf("%d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you have the number as text, you can just count its digits directly.  Otherwise you are going to need a "bignum" library, 10^100 is well beyond the range of any built-in integer type.

Comment: You can use the GMP https://gmplib.org/ to work with big integers in C and C++

Comment: `10^100` is guaranteed to fit a C `int` type.

Comment: 10 to the power of 100 in unsigned integer representation requires 333 bits. You will need a library for indefinite integers.

Comment: It can not be preserved with the primitive integer type. Use an array.

Comment: @Yunnosch How could you tell what the OP wants? There is certainly nothing in the post that excludes the interpretation that they mean xor.

Comment: "I was working on a problem to count number of digits in a number" --> show that code.  "I have tried it using limits.h but it did not work. "  --> show that code too.

Comment: @chux isn't it simply 100? :D

Comment: @chux I was solving the problem on Hackerearth here is the link:https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/implementation/basics-of-implementation/practice-problems/algorithm/simple-addition-2/

Comment: @NeerajSewani Post your code here that you are working on. An off-site link is insufficient.

Comment: @chux pasted the code.

Comment: The typical widest integer type is 64-bits, the unsigned version can handle 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.  This is far smaller than `pow(10,100)`.  So there are no standard C integer types that can meet your goal.  Instead read user input text in as something other than an _integer_, perhaps as a `double` or a _string_.  (nominated for re-open)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in C 10^100 can be easily stored to an `int`:

```
int xored = 10^100;
```

After that, `xored` will store 110.

```
1100100
0001010
-------
1101110
```

Comment: This is unbelievably pedantic. I love it!

Comment: Languages/compilers ARE pedantic.  I see no problem with this answer.  I do see a big problem with the question, though:(

Comment: This answer fully answers the question! What is more, it's the only one that answers it...

Comment: @xenteros thanks for your reply. But i asked to store an integer value to a variable of "10 to the power 100" range. You misunderstood  "^" for bitwise XOR operator.

Comment: @NeerajSewani The original post lacked "10 to the power 100" and `^` is specified by C as the _bitwise exclusive OR operator_, so  xenteros did not misunderstand `^`.

Comment: @NeerajSewani far enough. `^` is exactly bitwise XOR operator

Answer (score -3):

As others have said, you don't need to store it as a number. Make a character array of length 100. Initialize the values to something non-numeric. From CIN or however else you're getting the number, save it to that character array. Then count how many numbers there are before you get to a non-number.

## Pseudocode:

```
BigNumber = new char[100];

cout << "Input the number:\n";

cin >> BigNumber;

digits = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if( IsNumeric(BigNumber[i]) )
    {
        digits++;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}

cout << "That number is " << digits << " digits long";
```

Comment: This question is tagged C, not C++.

Comment: Not my DV. Others did say that, but the question tag is not C++. Saying "pseudocode" is a thin disguise for "inaccurate implementation".

Comment: Its just an example of the logic. I also didnt define variable types or initialize values. I don't write C code, but the process is really basic. I wrote Psedocode because that is what it is ... not full working code, but a representation of code logic. Pseudocode can look like anything.

Comment: 10**100 has 101 digits plus a null terminator. The allocated array is too small